# Select the entire datetime after grouping by date (without time)

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

I have a table which counts the number of users every 15 minutes, then records that number with the time in the DB.  Entries look like the following:

```
users1| users2 |Time_Stamp
15    | 0      |2014-03-15 13:00:00.000
35    | 15     |2014-03-15 13:15:00.000
12    | 55     |2014-03-15 13:30:00.000
2     | 115    |2014-03-15 13:45:00.000
0     | 5      |2014-03-15 14:00:00.000
2     | 115    |2014-03-16 12:45:00.000
123   | 15     |2014-03-16 13:00:00.000
```

What I need to do is select the max number of users (for a particular group) in a particular amount of time, in this case a day grouped between midnight for each day, then display the exact time when that even occurred.

In the above example, the output I would want would be:

```
max users1 |Time_Stamp
35         |2014-03-15 13:15:00.000
123        |2014-03-16 13:00:00.000
```

It's easy to get the max per day, and ignore the time stamp.

```
select cast(time_stamp as date) as "time", max(users1) as "c"
from Counts
where users1 > 0
group by cast(time_stamp as date)
```

Which gives

```
max users1 |Time_Stamp
35         |2014-03-15
123        |2014-03-16
```

In other words, I need the max number of users in a day, and the time when it happened.

I've already solved the problem, but it looks absolutely terrible.  Below is my solution.  Is there anyone who can help me come up with a better way?

Also, I'd like to accomplish the ability to not just have these readouts per day, but per hour, or per 6 hours.

```
select users1, TIME_STAMP
from counts c
    inner join (
        select 
            cast(abc.time as datetime) as "day_start", 
            dateadd(day,+1,cast(abc.time as datetime)) as "day_end",
            abc.c as "day_max"
        from (
            select cast(time_stamp as date) as "time", max(users1) as "c"
            from Counts
            where users1 > 0
            group by cast(time_stamp as date)
            ) abc
        ) t
        on t.day_max = c.users1
where c.TIME_STAMP >= t.day_start
    and c.TIME_STAMP < t.day_end
order by c.TIME_STAMP desc
```

EDIT:  Sometimes, the max values are not unique.  I'd like to be able to display each timestamp when the max value occures.

Example, then expected output, below.

```
users1| TIME_STAMP
137 | 2014-06-21 11:15:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 11:00:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 10:45:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 10:30:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 10:15:00.000
136 | 2014-06-21 10:00:00.000
136 | 2014-06-21 09:45:00.000
136 | 2014-06-21 09:30:00.000
136 | 2014-06-21 09:15:00.000
136 | 2014-06-21 09:00:00.000

users1| TIME_STAMP
137 | 2014-06-21 11:15:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 11:00:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 10:45:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 10:30:00.000
137 | 2014-06-21 10:15:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `group by` using `row_number()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
            row_number() over (partition by cast(time_stamp as date) order by users1 desc) as seqnum
      from counts c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return the row with the maximum value on each day.

EDIT:

If you want all rows with the max, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
            dense_rank() over (partition by cast(time_stamp as date) order by users1 desc) as seqnum
      from counts c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This works fantastically, but there's a part of my question I need to make more clear.  The max is not unique, so there could be multiple times when a max value occurs.  When I use your function, it picks only one.  I'll update my question to make this more clear.